# How to clear all 0 values from range except for one 0 value preceding data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in a Google sheet that looks like this:
[image]

The data updates daily with a new column added after Column "Date" and is intended to track how quickly my team moves through projects. I am wanting to chart the data as a scatterplot so that I can add Linear Trendlines for each series. However, these lines are affected by all of the 0 values. I would like them to start with the last 0 value that precedes the first non-zero data point. The easiest solution I can see would be to use a macro to clear 0 values from the table. I am struggling with how to

- A) run the trendline through 0 in google sheets as there isn't really an option I can see; or
- B) delete all 0 values except for where the cell to the left is greater than 0.

This is currently where I am at with Row C.
[image]

But would like it to look like the following:
[image]

With the table potentially looking like this (Note highlighted the row with a zero preceding a value >0):
[image]

Comment: You can use [slicers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en), but that will work like a filter that will remove these values from the spreadsheet too when you have it enabled. Another solution is to have a separate column with a formula such as `=IF(A1=0%,"",A1)`, so the `0.00%` values will be excluded when building the chart. You can also just remove these values from the spreadsheet (or have a text that says something like "No Data"), assuming this won't affect your use case!

Comment: Use a sepperate table for your chart that uses the original table as it's source but transforms it as you want.  Please consider putting some data in a markdown table or sharing a link to some sample data in case you want anyone to actually manipulate anything and not have to generate the source datas first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Blind Spots suggests in their comment, you can **Insert > Sheet** and use a formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet to copy the data from the current sheet, omitting trailing zeros, like this:

```
=map( 
  Sheet1!A1:ZZ, 
  lambda( 
    cell, 
    if( 
      (cell = 0) * iferror(offset(cell, 0, -1) = 0), 
      iferror(1/0), 
      cell 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The `iferror(1/0)` pattern will produce a truly blank value, which is different from a zero-length text string `""`.

Then set the data range of your chart so that it points to the new sheet.

Comment: Nice doubleunary. +10

Comment: Edited the answer to use correct offset and `map()` instead of `arrayformula()`.